# Complex lookup table in SQL

Tags: sql, excel, lookup-tables

I'm in the middle of migrating a mock-up database built in Excel to SQL, so apologies if I confuse my terms from either platform.

The Excel database has a computed field which takes a number of inputs and does a number of comparisons (string matches, date comparisons, wildcards, booleans, etc.) and returns a designation for that row. To enable easier logic edits and avoid a complex, hard-to-debug formula, I opted to create a reverse lookup table which contained every designation and their corresponding fields.

I'm looking to replicate this in SQL. Here's a silly example:

```
Lookup table

owned_fruit    desired_fruit    fruit_stock    designation
Apple          Apple            >=5            Committed Apple
Orange         Orange           >=5            Committed Orange
<>Orange       Orange           >=5            Switching to Orange
<>Apple        Apple            >=5            Switching to Apple
*              *                <5             Low stock


Data table

owned_fruit    desired_fruit    fruit_stock    designation <- this is the computed column
Apple          Apple            5              Committed Apple
Apple          Orange           1              Low Stock
Orange         Apple            7              Switching to Apple
Banana         Orange           20             Switching to Orange
```

I know I could achieve something like this with an endlessly complicated computed column formula, but it seems that would have the same drawbacks as a super long formula in Excel: hard to debug, hard to adjust.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Seems like you are looking for dynamic SQL. What dbms is used/planned for use?

Comment: To be honest it seems to me you are taking a complicated excel formula and just transcribing it into complicated db logic (computed columns, dynamic sql, sprocs, queries -- it can all still be very messy). I would take the time to think about what this does, what is it for, how could it be modeled more effectively, and basically how to improve it rather than just translate it.

Comment: @topsail the formula in Excel itself is not very complicated. It's a lookup against a pretty big table to *avoid* a complicated formula (enabling much easier editing and debugging). The ultimate goal is automatically categorizing a list of clients according to various datapoints, and AFAIK this seems like the most effective way to model it (in Excel, anyway).

Comment: Well, you would not normally put a computed column in a database merely to get a "looked up value". In the world of databases, you look up values when you need them, as part of your queries. So, the answer seems straightforward - put your "lookup table" in your DB, and refer to it as/when needed to get the needed ("looked up") values - for instance, in your queries and views.